# Angular 4 FormBuilder FormControl syntax

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

When using the reactive forms module, is there any reason to ever use the `FormControl` syntax when using `FormBuilder`? I wasn't sure if the second syntax was just sugar, or there was a reason to use one over the other at times.

```
// 1
buildForm() {
    this.AccountCreateForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        logonName: this.formBuilder.control(null, [
            Validators.required,
            Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$')
        ]),
        password: this.formBuilder.control(null, [
            Validators.required,
            Validators.minLength(8),
            Validators.maxLength(128),
            Validators.pattern('^((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\\W).*)$')
        ])
    })
}

// 2
buildForm() {
    this.AccountCreateForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        logonName: [null, [
            Validators.required,
            Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$')
        ]],
        password: [null, [
            Validators.required,
            Validators.minLength(8),
            Validators.maxLength(128),
            Validators.pattern('^((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\\W).*)$')
        ]]
    })
}
```

Comment: If you wanted only a single control then you would need that method, however as part of a larger group the second syntax is more succinct for the same outcome

Comment: I think it's a matter of personal preference. I prefer using the methods since I can quickly see when a group is started or a control. Using sub-groups makes it easier to move some of the form to child components. Where you just forward the group as a binding.